# What is a convolutional neural network

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, references, conv-neural-network, convolution

I have been studying neural networks and I recently found out about deep learning and convolutional neural networks. Can someone give me a newbie introduction to convolutional neural networks,  what is the intuition behind them, little bit about the theory (+ possible good references for details and pseudo-code). I do understand how convolution-operation is defined, but can't connect it into neural networks. I'm also just beginning with deep learning methods, so I don't have any experience with that.

Question shortly put: Could someone give an introduction to convolutional neural networks? I would appreciate to have answers to questions:

1. What?
2. Why?
3. How?

Comment: I think the question is too broad. Also, Murphy's and Bishop's book have good and gentle introductions.

Comment: Hi @bayerj could you give the name of the books? =) thank you for your help, okay, even a small introduction is enough :)

Comment: Chris Bishop "Pattern recognition and machine learning". Kevin Murphy "Machine learning: a probabilistic perspective".

Comment: If you understand how a fully-connected layer works, you might find [my drawings](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/409172) to be useful.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://cs231n.stanford.edu/) is an oft-cited course on Computer Vision (CV) to get you started.  [There](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/every-single-machine-learning-course-on-the-internet-ranked-by-your-reviews-3c4a7b8026c0) are a few more for when you get more advanced (also includes general ML courses).

I find video can be much more engaging, but of course the tradeoff is that if you're on the internet it's easier to get distracted.